# How to return HttpClient subscribe data to a component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to return data from a service using subscribe method.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DevRequestService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
    getListOfAgencies() {
        return this.http.get('https://example.com/api/agency').subscribe(data => {
            return data;
          });
    }
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.devRequestService.getListOfAgencies());
}
```

Below is the output that I'm getting in console.log instead of returning the object with the values:

`Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}`

Comment: That's correct, you're getting the subscriber. That's what `Observable.subscribe` returns, and that's what you're returning. Probably what you want is to `return this.http.get(...)`, and move the subscription into the component. Alternatively, you can expose the fetched data via another observable, as I've written about here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should subscribe for the data and assign it to a variable in component like below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.devRequestService.getListOfAgencies().subscribe((data) => {
      this.agencies = data;
   })
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in your .ts:
    private data$: Observable;

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$ = this.devRequestService.getListOfAgencies();
}
```

and in your .html template, this:

```
<div> {{ data$ | async }} </div>
```

in order to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load data to view, you should use new Subject in your service. For example:

```
export class PostService {
    subject = new Subject();
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    const httpRequest = new HttpRequest(
        'GET',
        '/your-url',
        body,
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'body'),
        }
    );
    this.httpClient.request(httpRequest).subscribe((res) => {
        if (res.type) {
            this.subject.next(res.body);
        }
    });

    return this.subject;
}
```

In component:

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
    posts: any;
    constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getPosts();
    }

    private getPosts() {
        this.posts = this.postService.getPosts();
    }
}
```

In view:

```
<app-post-item
    class="col-md-4"
    *ngFor="let post of posts | async"
    [post]="post">
</app-post-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem where I was not getting a response, but rather a subscriber instance. It turned out the server code was not returning a JSON parsable response. Seemed like a silent error, not sure why. But when I fixed the server code to return an object, I got the response.